# Search Paths Confusion in Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, clang, xcode4.6

In Xcode I added MailCore as a subproject, and target dependency. It works great on my machine. Sadly when I share the project with another collaborator, he's unable to get the header file to show up.

[image: My search paths]

Somehow his search paths have my folder names hardcoded in (as in andrewjl), is there a way to fix this in order to point to an analogous directory on his machine?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an absolute search path, use a relative one.

"$(SRCROOT)" is where your projectfile is located.

"$(SRCROOT)/AnotherFolder" for AnotherFolder is a peer of your project file

once add this variable, to the search path (after double tapping on the searchpaths line), you can add "$(SRCROOT)/Products/MyReceipt.........." and once you dismiss the add/remove searchPath popover, you'll see where the search path is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Your search paths are absolute paths. Write them as relative paths (relative to the project).